# Get notified when a presented ViewController is dismissed

Tags: ios, notifications, presentviewcontroller

I'm presenting a ViewController using `presentViewController`. I need to perform some operations when the presented ViewController dismisses itself. At the moment, I defined a protocol for the presenting ViewController and I call the corresponding method in the completion block of `dismissViewControllerAnimated` in the presented ViewController. Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use delegation and have the delegate perform the appropriate methods right before calling `dismissViewController`, use an unwind segue instead of `dismissViewController`, or do it the way you're doing it currently. It sounds like you're doing it the right way if you want the operations to be run immediately **after** the presented view controller dismisses itself; that's why the completion block exists in `dismissViewController`. Using delegation means the operations would be run immediately **prior** to the presented view controller's dismissal.

Answer (score 3):

I believe using delegate is the best way. But still you can use other alternative with the help of class NSNotificationCenter.

You can register/add observer notification for your VC (its parent view VC for present VC)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(myVCDismissNotification:) 
        name:@"MyVCDismissNotification"
        object:nil];
```

Define the method in same class (It will get call whenever the notification posted)

```
-(void) myVCDismissNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"MyVCDismissNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the Dismiss notification!");
         //You can use it in your way.
}
```

Be remember to use this function in your Parent VC.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

In present VC, when you dismiss the VC, call the below method

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"MyVCDismissNotification" 
        object:self];
```

For more description about notifications, you refer the Apple Docs. Happy Coding.